# Hide desktop icons and windows to show desktop wallpaper?

Tags: cocoa

How do you hide the desktop icons and the windows open to show the desktop wallpaper in cocoa?

Answer (score 0):

### Trying to show a preview??

---

If so you could try:

> - Showing a full-screen app with the image to simulate a preview.
> - Once user selects a wallpaper, use APIs provide to set that image as the
>     wallpaper.
>
>   (You could,minimise your app now)

I hope this is what you wanted to achieve...

GoodLUCK!!